# Smart contract Dataset on blocckhain

Tags: dataset, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

**I work on smart contracts and blockchain technology and I need to know how I can get a smart contract dataSet(solidity smart contracts)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few smart contract templates and examples here:

1. [OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/master/contracts)
2. [Smart Contract Basic Example](https://github.com/Turing-Chain/Smart-Contract-Modular-Template/tree/master/examples)
3. [Smart Contract Honeypot Defense](https://github.com/Turing-Chain/Smart-Contract-Modular-Template/tree/master/honeypots)
4. [Smart Contract Exploits](https://github.com/Turing-Chain/Smart-Contract-Modular-Template/tree/master/exploits)